# Effects of merging states on the limiting distribution of a Markov Chain

Tags: markov-chains

Consider a discrete time, homogeneous, finite state Markov chain given by a stochastic $n\times n$ matrix $M$.

We also have a cost vector $w$ of size $n$ with non-negative integer costs. The cost of the Markov chain $cost(M)$ is defined as $π\cdot w$, where $π$ is the limit-distribution of $M$, which satisfies $Mπ=π$ (if the stationary distribution is unique, then it's that). That is, the cost of $M$ is the expected cost.

Consider two states $q,s$ of $M$. *Merging* $q$ to $s$ means that we erase $q$ from the chain, and all incoming transitions to $q$ go to $s$ instead. Effectively, this means that we sum the two columns of $M$ corresponding to $q$ and $s$.

We want to prove (or find a counter-example for) the following claim:

> Claim: Given a Markov chain $M$, a cost vector $w$, and two states $q,s$, denote by $M_q$ and $M_s$ the chains obtained by eliminating $q$ to $s$ and $s$ to $q$, respectively, then either $cost(M_q)≤cost(M)$ or $cost(M_s)≤cost(M)$.

Note that the claim is not true if we just take $\pi$ to be a stationary distribution. Thus, we look at the limiting distribution from the initial state.

We actually have a solution when the chain is ergodic and strongly connected (i.e. one ergodic communication class).
Also, it is not hard to see that if $q$ and $s$ are not reachable from each other, then the claim is true. So the question is what happens when $q$ and $s$ are transient, and at least one of them is reachable from each other (the case where one is ergodic and the other is transient is not of interest to us, but a general proof would be nice).

Remark: this was posted on math.stackexchange, but got no responses.